# Set access token with Postman

Tags: rest, authentication, postman

I have a rest API and I want to send a request to it using Postman. The request should be send with a bearer authentication token. How can I add this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a header parameter with `Authorization` as key and `Bearer <insert_your_token_here>` as value.

Answer (score 3):

You have an "Authorization" tab on your request in Postman. You can choose "Bearer Token" and insert your token there.

Comment: This is actually even easier than mine.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of Postman you can directly use "Authorization" tab and choose Type as "Bearer Token" and provide your token there. Postman automatically add "Bearer" as prefix to your token and user it in headers.

However if your server implementation requires a different prefix then "Bearer", you can specify it in the Header Prefix field.